# View more.... option

Tags: php, mysql

I am using limit to display the latest 3 entries.  If there are more than 3 entries how can i show the option "view all".

HOw can i tweak the code or add a new code:

Code:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM messages where u_id = '$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();

echo "";

 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) {

  $otheris=mysql_result($result,$i,"sender_full_name"); 
  $sysid=mysql_result($result,$i,"sender_id");
   $dob=mysql_result($result,$i,"dob");

     // If $dob is empty
      if (empty($dob)) {

   $dob = "No new messages - 
   <a  id=missingdob href=/test.php?id=$uid>
   <bold>check later</bold></a>";
   }

     echo "<br><div id=linkcontain>
    <a id=otherlink href=$mem/profile.php?id=$uid>
     $manitis</a>
     <br><div id=dobpres>$dob</div></div>";

      echo "";

      $i++;
       }

        ?>
```

Comment: Remove the `LIMIT`? I don't understand what you're asking here

Comment: I'd say load it all in and then just show however many you want.  Create a button that just shows more instead of actually loading.  Less queries=better.

Comment: The above code will display the recent 3 messages.  If tehre are more than 3 messages in the database, i want to show the following two words "view more".  how can i do that using the code like the one above...

Comment: just remove the limit. Everything else is about your code (which you conveniently are not showing).

Comment: no such thing as not wanting to show.  the rest of the code just displays.  not necessary to show. plus stackoverflow formatting itself takes 5 extra minutes to display properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second query that counts the total number of messages.  If the count is greater than your limit (3), then display your message.

Comment: Yes.  that is exactly what i want.  But what code to i imiplement?

Comment: @AAA nobody can answer you that, because you're not showing any of your code except for the query